# jQuery selector for varying HTML structure

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working with a page which displays a product's price. Normally it looks like this:

```
<span id="priceText">
    $26.94
</span>
```

When the item is on sale, it looks like this:

```
<span id="priceText">
    <strike>$26.94</strike>
    <span class="salePrice">$25.00</span> 
</span>
```

I have a generic function which extracts the price from any page like so:

```
var getPrice = function(price_id) {
    return jQuery(price_id).text();
};
```

Where `price_id` is the id of the element which contains the price.

As is plainly obvious, this will not work with the above structure since the "sale" version will return both $26.94 and $25.00 if I set price_id to `priceText`

I do not have control over the html on the product's page, so I can't change the structure. I need to use the `getPrice` function on other pages which do not have this HTML structure, so I also want to avoid changing it.

What I am looking for is some sort of jQuery selector which will return $25.00 if the item is on sale, or $26.94 if it isn't. Something like "return all text inside of `priceText` NOT in a strike tag"

I currently have a custom snippet which does the following:

```
jQuery('#priceText .salePrice').length ? jQuery('#priceText .salePrice').text() : jQuery('#priceText strike').text()
```

However I want to avoid custom lines of code like this. I think this may not be possible using only jQuery selectors but I'm hoping someone proves me wrong!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [multiple selector](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector).

```
jQuery('#priceText .salePrice, #priceText:not(:has(.salePrice))').text()
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/2n82irHBgfGYXVRL2DOS?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: oh that's a thing of beauty! let my give it a try but I think this is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: this worked great, I had not thought to use multiple selectors AND :not selectors at the same time. that makes a lot of sense. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could reduce your condition by this:

```
($('#priceText .salePrice') || $('#priceText strike')).text()
```

Comment: this is certainly better than my current snippet. the ideal solution would still be some sort of "conditional" selector but i'm not actually sure that exists